# Angular4/HTML - multiple yes or no radio groups using *ngFor

Tags: html, angular, ngfor, radio-group, angular4-forms

I am using *ngfor to display values of one or more households. Each of the household has one pair of yes or radio button group.

So, for example, if I display two households I will end up with two pairs of yes or no radio button groups. The dilemma is, usually we give the same name to a radio button group so as to make yes or no option mutually exclusive.

If I do that I am not able to separate the radio group in the first household from the radio group from the second household since they are all named the same, and if I select yes from the first group the yes in the second group gets selected and vice versa.

If I give different names to the yes radio and no radio then I am able to select both yes and no in the same group (which shouldn't happen).

How do you think I can solve this?

Snippets attached below.

EDIT:

I had a follow up question to that. I am trying to show/hide a help text when they click each household's form group. How do u think I can write an *ngIf for it because I tried it and it didn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

```
<div *ngFor="let HH of households; let i = index;" class="col-sm-8 col-xs-12 left_col_padding">
   <div class="script"></div>
    <h5> Please select Yes or No</h5>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-8 padding_none">
        <div class="radio radio-primary radio-inline radio-inline_d" style=" width:auto">
            <input aria-labelledby="Yes"  type="radio" name="selectIncome{{i}}" id="selectIncome{{i}}" required  >
            <label[innerHTML]="Yes"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio radio-primary radio-inline radio-inline_d" style=" width:auto">
          <input aria-labelledby="No"  type="radio" name="selectIncome{{i}" id="selectIncome{{i}}" required  >
          <label  [innerHTML]="No"></label>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you re-create the situation on https://stackblitz.com/?

Comment: ok let me try that

Answer (score 2):

you need to change name attribute `name="{{'selectIncome'+i}}"` instead of `name="selectIncome{{i}}"` this.

here is small working example: [multiple group radio button](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1ezwtr)

may be you need something like this: [multiple group radio button with value](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mnx2ew)

Comment: Thanks a lot Sanoj!!,
I had a follow up question to that. i am trying to show/hide a help text when they click each household's form group. how do u think i can write an *ngIf for it because i tried it and it didnt seem to work. any suggestions?